# How to make Angular.js routing urls into dynamic, so urls won't be long

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

So while I'm making my first angular app, I see that the urls change for different pages, which is what's suppose to happen. So say I click a button and this

```
http://localhost:63342/angularSPA/app/view2/view2.html
```

changes to

```
http://localhost:63342/angularSPA/app/view2/view3.html.
```

What will the users see once I upload this all to something like heroku or my own domain. Everytime I route them to a page, will they see this long URL and will it change everytime I click a button or something?

Comment: That is what your users will see. It will only change when the route or its parameters are changed.

Comment: Instead of seeing `localhost:63342` they will see `yourdomainname.com:63342` in the URL. The rest will remain the same.

Comment: What If i have a home.html page and I have 2 buttons: 1.dogs and 2. cats. 
WHen they click dogs, a list of dogs should come, and same with cats. Do i have to create 2 differnet html pages for them and the users will see angularSPA/app/view2/dog.html AND angularSPA/app/view2/cat.html??

This looks so bad though, how do I just display the content without changing the url

Comment: If you don't want the URL to change, load partials into your primary view. There are a lot of different resources available online to learn about using them.

Comment: Is this easier  with ui-routing or ng-routing

Answer (score 0):

you only need to upload what is inside the app folder. so this:

```
http://localhost:63342/angularSPA/app/view2/view2.html
```

will become this:

```
http://localhost:63342/view2/view2.html
```

if you put your index.html file in your root/app directory it will get even shorter:

```
http://localhost:63342/index.html
```

However, you can use a number of directives to achieve page changes without changing the url.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

You could, but I don't know why you would, have your entire site be under index.html.

However, that means that the user's browser will have to load ALL of your 'stuff' before displaying the single page app. It also means you won't be able to use the power of routing.

Also, angular adds # in there.

Here is a good ui-router tutorial.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: But all the Apps I've seen don't have long urls, its just like domain.com/ something.html, which changes to domain.com/something2.html, and features within those something.html change without url changing! Isn't that what angular is suppose to be for? so the url doesn't look ugly

Comment: No, angular is not there to keep the url from looking ugly.... Angular is a helpful javascript framework which provides default functionality to make building a single page application easier. As I said in my answer, you can get domain.com/something2.html if you put your views in the root directory

Comment: What if I have like 100+ views. AKA over 100 buttons/clicks that perform something. All of them in the root, is that okay?